# Python vs. C# Twitter API libraries

Tags: c#, python, api, twitter

I have experience with both .NET(5yrs) and Python(1yr) and I want to create a simple web project with Twitter as the backbone. I have experience with AppEngine, and have always wanted to try Azure. I'm going to make extensive use of sending and parsing tweets from lots of users at a time, and since I've set a short deadline for this I'd like to take the shortest path possible. So does anyone have any experience with both of these, or have any advice?

A quick look at the twitter API libraries(http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Libraries) gave me this for python:

- python-twitter by DeWitt Clinton. This library provides a pure Python interface for the Twitter API.
- python-twyt by Andrew Price. BSD licensed Twitter API interface library and command line client.
- twitty-twister by Dustin Sallings. A Twisted interface to Twitter.

and this for C#:

- Yedda Twitter Library by Yedda. Every Twitter API method has an equivalent .NET method in this wrapper library.
- TwitterooCore API by Eric Willis/RareEdge Design Group. Binary .NET library that can be used in any .NET project.
- Twitterizer originally by DigitallyBorn, but now open source. Written for .NET 2.0.
- tweet# by Daniel Crenna. "100% coverage of the REST and Search APIs".

Answer (score 4):

The best advice is to use whatever language you are most comfortable with.

Myself and a colleague have recently re-written our Twitter web-app's entire back-end with a C# service, and the decision for us came down to which library best suited the purpose.  A number of the libraries have varying 'features', some are more complete than others: we decided which to select based purely on trying them out, and seeing which were the best-optimised, and made our job easiest.

I would make a recommendation for a C# library, but the playing field changes so very quickly, and we've changed implementations a couple of times, as Twitter has deprecated various aspects of their API, and some have updated more quickly than others.

Answer (score 4):

I would put my vote in for this twitter library; http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

I've used it in 10+ projects that I can think of and its been very good. I've actually been using the dev version in a number of projects too and found it stable and has many more features.

Comment: yeah, I'm trying it out right now as well(just because VS tooks such a long time to download from my MSDNAA xD), but I can't seem to get it working in AppEngine, keep getting the error they cover here: http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/issues/detail?id=59

Answer (score 3):

[LINQ to Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) is available too, covers the entire Twitter API, and works with VB, C#, and Delphi Prism.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

You can use both .NET and Python ... IronPython.  IronPython will work with Yedda. [1](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Tweet)

Answer (score 0):

I am using [this python library](http://mike.verdone.ca/twitter/) for one of my project.

It's really easy to use and yet very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

python-twyt by Andrew Price. BSD licensed Twitter API interface library and command line client.

is my python library of choice. it's fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of experience with the Twitter API (I'm Digitallyborn, author of Twitterizer).

I would say go with what is easiest to you. There are a lot of great libraries out there for every language.